# Enable the menu item of my Visual studio extension only when code window is open

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'd like to enable my extension menu item only when code editor is open.

I try to detect when Code window is opening with the following code without successful result...

```
private void MenuItem_BeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleMenuCommand menuCommand = sender as OleMenuCommand;
        if (null != menuCommand)
        {
            IVsMonitorSelection monitorSelection =  this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IVsMonitorSelection)) as IVsMonitorSelection;
            int pfActive;

            Guid codeWindowGuid = VSConstants.UICONTEXT_CodeWindow;
            uint solutionExistCookie;
            monitorSelection.GetCmdUIContextCookie(ref codeWindowGuid, out solutionExistCookie);
            monitorSelection.IsCmdUIContextActive(solutionExistCookie, out pfActive);

            menuCommand.Enabled = (pfActive == 1);
        }
    }
```

Although `IsCmdUIContextActive` is returing `S_OK`, I'm always receiving pfActive as false even if code window is really opened..

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Not yet! I think the problem may be in the way of loading the package rather than the visibility fields. I'm investigating!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to add `out` keyword in your `IsCmdUIContextActive` method signature in the place where it is defined?

Comment: No, it it works. It seems GetCmdUIContextCookie only works with some GUIDs and UICONTEXT_CodeWindow is not in the list...
I'm looking for alternatives...

Comment: Specifying `out` at a call site when the matching parameter in the method signature is not marked as `out` should generate a compiler error, not odd runtime behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

[Component Diagnostics](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulHarrington.ComponentDiagnostics) extension can show you all currently active contexts so that you choose the needed one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checking [DTE.ActiveWindow.Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.window.document?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#EnvDTE_Window_Document) is not null is probably the easiest way to check for an active editor.